# Failed Login Attempts

Tags: identityserver4

Does Identity Server 4 supports suspension of accounts after a number of failed login attempts?

I know there are better ways of dealing with failed login attempts, like asking the user for more forms of identification when they eventually successfully log in.  But is it easy enough to extend Identity Server 4 to suspend accounts after x amounts of failed logins, by IP address, etc.?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

IdentityServer does not support user lockout by default. 
You can setup ASP.NET Identity to handle that for you. In fact IdentityServer has a sample integration with ASP.NET Identity.
You can setup user lockout in the Identity options in the ConfigureServices method.

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
{
    options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
    options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 20;
});
```

Source:
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/293622b8438d27f4c9c2574e43fe92a22560ac6b/Quickstarts/6_AspNetIdentity/src/IdentityServerWithAspNetIdentity/Startup.cs#L42

Comment: That sounds great, I'll look further into that.

Comment: This seems a very appropriate solution, I'd love to know why someone down-voted it.

Comment: There's more detail in this other answer that I needed to get everything working https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44680939/asp-net-core-identity-settings-not-working